# EF Core 2.1 evaluates locally when subquery and aggregate after Grouping

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, entity-framework-core

So EF Core 2.1 evaluates GroupBy LINQ expressions on the SQL server (when using the SQL provider).

This is awesome *however* I have an issue when the query gets a little more complex.

The model in use for these queries is:

```
public class Invoice
{
    public string Status {get; set;}
    public string InvoiceType {get; set;}
    public decimal InvoicePayments {get; set;}
    public decimal EligibleValue {get; set;}
}
```

**This LINQ statement is run completely in SQL Server:**

```
data
    .GroupBy(i => new { i.Status, i.InvoiceType })
    .Select(i => new 
    {
        i.Key, 
        Count = i.Count(), 
        Total = i.Sum(x => x.EligibleValue)
    });
```

and generates the following SQL

```
SELECT 
    [i].[Status], 
    [i].[InvoiceType], 
    COUNT(*) AS [Count], 
    SUM([i].[EligibleValue]) AS [Col1]
FROM [Invoice] AS [i]
GROUP BY [i].[Status], [i].[InvoiceType]
```

**This LINQ statement works but performs the GroupBy *in memory*:**

```
data
    .GroupBy(i => new { i.Status, i.InvoiceType })
    .Select(i => new 
    { 
        i.Key, 
        Count = i.Count(), 
        TotalLessThan100 = i.Where(x => x.InvoicePayments < 100).Sum(y => y.EligibleValue),
        TotalLessThan500 = i.Where(x => x.InvoicePayments < 500).Sum(z => z.EligibleValue)
    });
```

I get some warnings in the Output window:

```
    The LINQ expression 'GroupBy(new <>f__AnonymousType0`2(Status = [i].Status, InvoiceType = [i].InvoiceType), [i])' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally.

The LINQ expression 'Count()' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally.

The LINQ expression 'where ([x].InvoicePayments < 100)' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally.

The LINQ expression 'where ([x].InvoicePayments < 500)' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally.

The LINQ expression 'Sum()' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally.
```

And the generated SQL does not have the GroupBy, just the initial query.

*Is there any way I can define this query to be fully executed on the SQL Server?*

Comment: maybe move `.Where()` out from `.Select()`

Comment: And do you know where I could put it? I need the `.Where()` to be evaluated on the grouped data. I'll edit the query to show a little bit more of the full scenario - sorry.

Comment: You could try to use `.Sum(x => x.InvoicePayments < 100 ? x.EligableValue : 0)` to get rid of the where clause. Worth a try at least.

Comment: Thanks @Dirk that was a good suggestion but it still gives me the good old warning
`The LINQ expression 'GroupBy(new <>f__AnonymousType0``2(Status = [i].Status, InvoiceType = [i].InvoiceType), [i])' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally.`
followed by the other messages (although this time without the warning about the `Where`)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The first rule to follow is to avoid `Where` and predicate version of `Count` on `GroupBy` result and use the conditional `Sum` where possible. EF6 was able to translate such constructs, but with very inefficient SQL.

So in general you need to rewrite the query like this:

```
data
    .GroupBy(i => new { i.Status, i.InvoiceType })
    .Select(g => new
    {
        g.Key,
        Count = g.Count(),
        TotalLessThan100 = g.Sum(i => i.InvoicePayments < 100 ? i.EligibleValue : 0),
        TotalLessThan500 = g.Sum(i => i.InvoicePayments < 500 ? i.EligibleValue : 0)
    });
```

However EF Core 2.1 `GroupBy` translation improvements does not include `Sum` with other than a simple property selector, so the above still uses client evaluation. Most likely it will be fixed in some future release, but until then, can use the following trick - add intermediate projection (`Select`) before `GroupBy` containing all the fields needed later, including the calculated, and then use them inside the aggregates after the `GroupBy`:

```
data
    .Select(i => new
    {
        i.Status,
        i.InvoiceType,
        LessThan100 = i.InvoicePayments < 100 ? i.EligibleValue : 0,
        LessThan500 = i.InvoicePayments < 500 ? i.EligibleValue : 0,
    })
    .GroupBy(i => new { i.Status, i.InvoiceType })
    .Select(g => new
    {
        g.Key,
        Count = g.Count(),
        TotalLessThan100 = g.Sum(i => i.LessThan100),
        TotalLessThan500 = g.Sum(i => i.LessThan500)
    });
```

which is translated to:

```sql
SELECT [i].[Status], [i].[InvoiceType], COUNT(*) AS [Count], SUM(CASE
    WHEN [i].[InvoicePayments] < 100.0
    THEN [i].[EligibleValue] ELSE 0.0
END) AS [TotalLessThan100], SUM(CASE
    WHEN [i].[InvoicePayments] < 500.0
    THEN [i].[EligibleValue] ELSE 0.0
END) AS [TotalLessThan500]
FROM [Invoice] AS [i]
GROUP BY [i].[Status], [i].[InvoiceType]
```

Comment: Thanks @ivan! Works perfectly

Comment: Thank you very much.  Interestingly I didn't quite get mine right and did the same thing as just adding i.EligibleValue into my first Select and left the calculations in the Sum in the 2nd select and that also worked correctly.

Answer (score 1):

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2018/05/30/announcing-entity-framework-core-2-1/

"We now support translating it to the SQL GROUP BY clause in most common cases."

Presumably your case is not 'common'?

I had this problem in 2.0.  I solved it by hand-crafting a lot of methods to generate SQL.  yes, it was a PITA but I wanted to stick with Core for various other reasons.

Comment: I guess "common cases" is a matter of opinion ;-) 

I'm not sure we want to go down the road of hand-crafting the translation of `GroupBy` to SQL statements though (but thanks for the suggestion).

Comment: I saw this same line and felt the same. For any kind of reporting this is essential.